# Using hasMany relation and cascading ORM level in loopback4

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop, loopback4

I have created 2 models `Author` and `Books` where Author has `hasMany` relation with Book and Book has `belongsTo` relation with author.

While saving data using ORM models the cascading is not happening i.e

```
{
    "authorId": 1,
    "name": "qwery",
    "experience": 2,
    "books": [{
        "BookId": 12,
        "category": "string"
    }]
}
```

The above should create a Author record in Author table and create a Book record with the authorId in Book table, which is not happening whereas from belongsTo it can able to create an Author record with just authorId.

You can find the code in the [following GIT](https://github.com/Ambay54/loopback_postgres.git)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a AuthorBookController to connect the two.  Please see example code in here: https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/blob/master/examples/todo-list/src/controllers/todo-list-todo.controller.ts